# Resuming from Javascript in WinDbg does still results in interactive shell

Tags: javascript, windbg

I'm attempting to use the new Javascript features in WinDbg in order to script collecting some data.

The basic setup of what I have is that I have one script, which generates a bunch of breakpoints, and a second script which is actually invoked by the breakpoints.

The objective of the script which is invoked by the breakpoints is to log some data, and then resume execution -- I never want to be dropped into an interactive prompt. Unfortunately that's not the case. Here's the script:

```
"use script";


function invokeScript() {
    // If the process is not a content process (e.g. parent or GPU), exit out.
    var cl = host.currentProcess.Environment.EnvironmentBlock.ProcessParameters.CommandLine.ToDisplayString();
    if (cl.slice(-5, -1) !== " tab") {
        host.diagnostics.debugLog("Exiting because not tab: " + cl.slice(-5, -1) + "\n");
    } else {
        host.diagnostics.debugLog("===WIN32K-START===\n");
        for (var frame of host.currentThread.Stack.Frames) {
            host.diagnostics.debugLog(frame.toString() + "\n");
        }
        host.diagnostics.debugLog("===WIN32K-END===\n");
    }
    host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("gc");
}
```

My expectation, based on Microsoft's examples, is that `host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("gc")` would resume execution, but it does not (apologies about the screenshot):

[image: WinDbg giving me an interactive prompt] (the `gc`s there were all entered by hand).

Edit: Further testing shows that this occurs only in the WinDbg preview from the Microsoft Store, the existing WinDbg continues to work ok, so I'm inferring that this is a bug.